# SecAst Web Interface

Tags: asterisk, secast

Im running an asterisk 13 server with a freepbx frontend and I've be trying to get SecAst working properly.
I've installed and configured it and it's running without errors.
I can telnet into it ok but if I try and use the web interface I get the following message "A connection with the SecAst software cannot be established. Make sure that SecAst is running, and that the socket file (/tmp/secast.sock) is present." The .sock file is present and readable.
Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry if this sounds simplistic...but have you refreshed your browser?  If the browser window is open before SecAst fully starts you can see this fault.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i've refreshed my browser and also used different browser. Further investigation has revealed two potential problems. From the diagnostic program there is a message asking me to add an entry in the /etc/services file. I think I've done that ok but the messages persists. The other thing that might be an issue is the /tmp/secast.sock file. It exists but when I try and open it with an editor, it won't open. I'm not sure if that is normal or not.

Comment: The /tmp/secast.sock file is a "socket" file so do not attempt to edit it.  It gets delete/created with SecAst startup.  If SecAst starts normally then don't worry about the /etc/services file.  I suspect the clue is in your secast log file (set debug to all to get lots of details)

Comment: I've checked the secast log file (afterturning on debug) and all i can see is a problem writing to one of the performance tables. I'm assuming that the web interface is independent of this. I've also checked the httpd logs to see if they throw up anything but they don't.

Comment: Between the secast and http log the answer should be in there.  The next steps steers into user support (not product support) - I'd suggest you email support@telium.ca as this gets outside Server Fault guidelines.   If there is a general solution please post here for all users.

Comment: That's great. I'll do that and post back. Thanks for your help so far.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure the /tmp directory has rwx permissions for the account under which you start HAAst

If the problem is still not solved look at the [manufacturer's forum](https://telium.io/en/security-for-asterisk/forums/) where an almost identical problem is explained and solved.